# A dynamic state is understood as a state in which.../The dynamic state is understood as the state in which...?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

Which one is correct:

1. "An invention should be described in its dynamic state. A dynamic state is understood as a state in which... "
2. "An invention should be described in its dynamic state. The dynamic state is understood as the state in which..."

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> "An invention should be described in its dynamic state. **The** dynamic state is understood as **a** state in which... "

> "An invention should be described in its dynamic state. **A** dynamic state is understood as **the** state in which... "

In this case, the articles can be used interchangeably.

Comment: This is wrong (the bit about *definite articles must be used for dynamic states*). And while that change to include both ***the** [dynamic state]* and ***a** [state]* isn't actually *invalid*, don't think it's helpful to gratuitously introduce it here. Especially not without mentioning that it would still be perfectly "grammatical, syntactically valid" if you'd reversed it to ***A** dynamic state is understood as **the** state in which...*

Comment: But definite articles are about specific quantities, aren't they? Then how came my explanation is incorrect?

Comment: You mean to say, I should include both the possibilities, *The* dynamic state...*a* state.., as well as, *A* dynamic state...*the* state..?

Comment: Generally you use the indefinite article when defining at term because you are *not* actually talking about something very specific, you talking about any and all states that may be labelled "dynamic". So you say, "**A** dynamic state is understood as..."

Comment: There are general principles governing when we might use definite, indefinite, or "zero" articles, but they're complicated, and there are a lot of exceptions. In the *exact* context cited here, both instances could validly use either form. And I personally can't see any reason to suppose that ***The** dynamic state is defined as **a** state where...* carries any significantly different implications to ***A** dynamic state is defined as **the** state where...*

Comment: I see. I will edit to using both the articles interchangeably.